# how to make a specific background in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, background-color

[image]

I Want to make a container background like the one in the picture

How did he create it

i try by using gradient option but not have a nice result ?

Comment: Look, I would make this background with an image and apply it to the background of the container using the decoration image.

Comment: ok but without a circles ,just the background

Comment: Yes, just the gray background with the lines, the larger circles would be developed using other widgets, even because there is the issue of adapting the screen to other sizes, the larger circles were better using other widgets in my opinion.

Comment: I think you're looking for RadialGradient, check this link: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-radialgradient-examples

Comment: @harundemir918 I tried to make a lot of backgrounds, but I didn't get the good result